# ActionCable stopped working after upgrading to Ruby 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

For context, my current production server runs on AWS EC2, with a Application Load Balancer in front, the server stack is Nginx + Passenger + Redis (5.0.6), currently running Ruby 2.7.7 using RBENV, I use ActionCable for some real time messaging on the "/cable" endpoint, and it works fine. The Rails version is 6.1.6.1

But after upgrading to Ruby 3.0.5, suddenly I am getting "Websocket is closed before the connection is established"

[image: Websocket is closed before the connection is established, in web browser]

Here's the nginx error.log :

```
18:17:22 [error] 9475#9475:
*56 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream. client: 172.30.21.12
server: request:
"GET /cable HTTP/1.1". upstream: "passenger :unix:/tmp/passenger.AW7j1af/agents.s/core:".
```

[image: Nginx error logs]

My Nginx configuration currently looks like this :

```
http {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 60;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  client_body_buffer_size 20m;
  client_max_body_size 50M;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";

  passenger_log_level 3;
  passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
  passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
  passenger_max_pool_size 5;
  passenger_min_instances 5;

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;
    passenger_max_request_queue_size 200;

    root /var/www/my_app_name/current/public;

    location /cable {
      passenger_app_group_name myapp_name_production_websocket;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The ActionCable related code is :

```
// app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `rails generate channel` command.
//
//= require action_cable
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./channels

(function() {
  this.App || (this.App = {});

  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer();

}).call(this);
```

I have mounted "/cable" in the routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

I have read all ActionCable + Nginx related questions in StackOverflow, and I have tried putting proxy headers in the Nginx config files like this :

```
location /cable {
  passenger_app_group_name myapp_name_production_websocket;
  passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;

  /* I have tried adding this, no effect */
  proxy_read_timeout 300s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

I restarted the server after adding these, but the same error still persists.

I have updated passenger gem and websocket-ruby gem to latest.

I have narrowed down the issue to be related to Ruby version changes, as when I revert back the Ruby version to 2.7.7, then everything works as usual, it stopped working when I upgrade Ruby to 3.0.5

Comment: Could you share the rails server logs too please ? Looks like the server is closing the connection before responding to the request.

Comment: @SébastienP. , I have just checked the rails logs (in app/logs/production.log), there isn't a GET "/cable", despite multiple connection attempt from web browsers, I am guessing the connection got terminated before it reaches the Rails server

Comment: Hmm I don't think that the issue is coming from the connection between nginx and the rails server as you said that the issue happens only with the new ruby version. Is the app working well otherwise (apart from the `/cable` endpoint) ? What about your local env ? You're not able to reproduce with the same ruby version ?

Comment: Yes, the app is working well otherwise (apart from the `/cable` endpoint). I couldn't reproduce with the same ruby version on my local development env, as the actioncable works fine on my local env with the same ruby version (3.0.5). The difference I could think of is that my local env uses ws:// (not secured), but the production uses wss:// (secured)

Comment: When you said that you've restarted the server, you're talking about the EC2 instance, the nginx process or the rails server ? If you apply some changes on the nginx config you need to reload the config or restart the instance.
 
What's the rails' version BTW ?

Comment: you need to check your Nginx log file to see the detailed error

Comment: Do you use redis?

Comment: @SébastienP. I have tried restarting the EC2 instance, and restarting nginx (sudo service nginx restart), restarting rails server (passenger-config restart app), after restarting those, the actioncable issue still persist unfortunately, the Rails version is 6.1.6.1

Comment: @mollywind yes I am using Redis for the actioncable, the Redis is a separate Elastic Cache instance

Comment: @SaiqulHaq  I have checked the nginx error.log (I have posted this in the question) and the access.log, is these two correct?

Comment: what Redis version are you using? sometimes I have found that the connection URL has changed depending on the version and that is why it is not able to make the connection

Comment: @mollywind I just checked, the Redis version is 5.0.6 . Sidekiq works fine though strangely (Sidekiq is using Redis as well)

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: @anothermh thanks for the explanation, I have edited the post to include text format of the Nginx error log

Comment: **UPD:** nvm, haven't noticed the "upgraded passenger" part. ("web socket-ruby" is not relevant). What about Action Cable version, btw? Also, "websocket-driver" worth checking (as well as other Action Cable deps, such as "nio4r").

I'm not very familiar with Passenger (and, tbh, don't understand why people use it at all), but since you narrowed the problem down to Ruby version, and it's Ruby 2.7 vs. Ruby 3, my only clue/question would be: have you tried upgrading the corresponding gems (like,`passenger`)? Maybe, it's just a bug somewhere in the web server (related to kwargs changes in Ruby).